# How to set notify If user already logged in the systems

Tags: php

I have a code like this :

```
include ("config.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$do = $_GET['do'];

if($do=="login")
{
    $cek = mysql_query("SELECT password, user_level FROM t_users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($cek)==1)
    {
        $c = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $c['username'];
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $c['user_level'];

        if($c['user_level']=="supervisor")
        {
            header("location:supervisor.php");
        }

        else if($c['user_level']=="user")
        {
            header("location:home.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="root")
        {
            header("location:administrator.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="manager")
        {
            header("location:manager.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="admin")
        {
            header("location:admin.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="director")
        {
            header("location:director.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.html');
    }
}
else if($do=="logout")
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
    $last_logged_out = date("j-F-Y, G:i ");
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    mysql_query("update t_users set last_logged_out='$last_logged_out', ip_address='$ip_address' WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");

    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
    header("location:index.html");
}
```

How can I give the function code if someone logged in and the same time or different time someone logged in to with a same username and then I want the systems will be notify that user already logged in, so user with same username can't login until user before logged out.

Someone can help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: Your source is really dangerous. The SQLs contains a SQL injections! The other files may be not protected. the header redirection doesn't meet the RFC - you have to use fqdn/file syntax. You may access not set variables. Take a look into the php error log.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try to add status in your session. Say for instance, if user has logged-in, status = 1 and vice versa, so every time that user tries to log in then you can freely do whatever action you want if that happens. Cheers.

Comment: can you please give me an example ? Because actually I have'nt got a logics. Please...

Comment: every time a user logs in, make the status = 1, this is assuming you already have a status field in the table together with the username, password, etc. You can change the status to 1 only after the username and password is inputted correctly. Hence, if user and pass is correct, make status = 1, then make a query checking if that username and password has a status = 1, then that solves it all.

Answer (score 0):

What about when a user logs in, setting a column in the database, e.g. `loggedin` to 1 and on subsequent logins check if that column is set to 1 and if it is then don't allow the login until whoever is logged in under that username logs out, then you will need to set that column to 0 to allow subsequent logins.

You might need some sort of timeout so that no one person can just log in and stay logged in as that user forever.

Answer (score 0):

1) Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

2) You must store information about logged user in a place, where you can get it for any user (ie NOT in $_SESSION). You can store it in database for example.

But your problem is, how to know, that user logged oout. If user do not log out (only close web browser), the user login will be locket "forewer". You can consider some timeout - if user do not any action on the web longer than 1 hour, you log him off when any other user try to log in. (You should change timeout every time the user do anything on your web).